# crmURL with selectedChild parameter?

Tags: extension

I'm trying to do something like the following in my extension's template:

```
{capture assign=contactUrl}{crmURL p='civicrm/contact/view' q="reset=1&id=`$contactId`&selectedChild=jobs" h=0}{/capture}
<a href="{$smarty.capture.contactUrl}">View Contact's Jobs</a>
```

But the selectedChild does not show up on the resulting URL. We do have a contact summary tab for Jobs in our case (part of the extension), and it does work if I hand type that parameter into the url. But not in smarty.

What is the right way to assign the correct crmURL (so the right URL works with any CMS) with the selectedChild parameter included? Or is this method no longer how we can direct to a specific tab on the contact summary page?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use `$contactUrl` instead of `$smarty.capture.contactUrl`

Try replacing the last line with:

```
<a href="{$contactUrl}">View Contact's Jobs</a>
```